# Facebook Graph API with Node JS and Sails JS

Tags: node.js, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, sails.js

As I've said in my previous posts, I'm learning how to use Node JS & Sails JS. Now I'm trying to integrate facebook's graph API in my web application. I searched and went through facebook's developer's site but somehow I'm still finding a hard time understanding what I should do. I already have an app in facebook, so I already have the app id and so on.

Now, I already have a facebook login button in my login.ejs under views

```
 <fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" onlogin="OnRequestPermission();">
 </fb:login-button>
```

And the facebook javascript sdk which is loaded in my layout.ejs

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'myAPPID',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.3',
      status     : true
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Question is, how will I be able to get the user access token and what is the best way to store it? And how will I be able to use the graph API in my controller? Should I install a node module or create my own? Also what is the best approach in using API's other than graph api, like twitter's api, alongside node & sails?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the access token by registering a callback method to be executed on the Facebook JAvaScript SDK's `auth.login` event. This is documented [here].(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.3)

But in fact you don't need to handle or even store the access token if you are using the JavaScript SDK. You can just call e.g. [`FB.api(path, method, params, callback)`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api) to make Graph API requests, and that will make sure an access token is sent as part of the request.